# Are Eigenvector Centrality Rankings Meaningful for Bottom Rankings?

Tags: data-visualization, social-network

I want to prune an undirected network of the least important nodes.

The eigenvector centrality measure seems like a good way to measure the importance of a node for my purposes.

However, I read on wikipedia that centrality measures may be very unstable after the first few rankings.

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality  (This example refers to PageRank but the article goes on to state this applies to centrality measure in general: 
""While the failure of centrality indices to generalize to the rest of the network may at first seem counter-intuitive, it follows directly from the above definitions"

So my question is:
Can an Eigenvector Centrality ranking be useful in pruning away the least central nodes?  Or would it be too unstable at lower rankings to give me a good list of candidate for pruning?

Comment: How many nodes are in your network, and how many of them are you intending to prune?

Comment: I'm not sure yet but an estimate would be: 100k node network and the need to prune 20k.

Comment: I wonder if the stability issues are still relevant at that scale. I have a feeling that they aren't but I have no proof for it.

Comment: I've no idea myself.  It would it nice to have a sense of it on the theoretical level first but I might just try doing it and see how it works out.

Comment: You could also try estimating the stability by bootstrapping the centrality estimates, using something like QAP to draw the bootstrap replicates

Comment: That's a good idea.  I will try it on samples first.  Will update when I find out more.

Comment: The actual resolution was my boss saying "Eigen What?! We are not using that."  I was young and innocent :)